# cygnus in Docker: How to fixe the OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I got this error on cygnus [instance in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/cygnus-ngsi/~/dockerfile/):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Increase the JVM size in the docker ini file.

Comment: you have a jmx assigned in your docker file increase that and verify

Comment: Not being an expert on Docker, maybe you can pass `JAVA_OPTS` as an environment variable: `docker run -e JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g' cygnus-ngsi`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cygnus configure the JAVA_OPTS with a limited value, you can modify this value updating the JAVA_OPTS variable, so in order that you docker container set this variable when it is building the container you can add inside of the dockerfile of Cygnus the following env variable:
ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g'

That line allows you a heap of memory of 1Gb.

Another option is that you create the container and after that enter inside of it and check what is the value of JAVA_OPTS and set to -Xmx1g.

Best Regards,